# Mpdf displaying one letter per page

Tags: mpdf

I'm adapting [this](https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/pdf-from-every-page-of-website.html) example to make a plugin for Kirby and I seem to make it work for creating the current URL and create a pdf.

So basically www.website.com/makepdf?url=http.website.com/page returns a pdf but is making one letter per page( more than a thousand pages!).

any experts in Mpdf who could give a helping tip?

this is the code i'm using trying:

```
<?php
@include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
Kirby::plugin('getkirby/pluginkit', [
    'routes' => [
        [
            'pattern' => 'en/makepdf',
            'action' => function () {


                $url = urldecode($_REQUEST['url']);
                if (count($_POST) > 0) {

                    $ch = curl_init($url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

                    foreach($_POST as $name => $post) {
                        $formvars = array($name => $post . " \n");
                    }

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formvars);
                    $html = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);

                } elseif (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
                    $html = file_get_contents($url);

                } else {
                    $ch = curl_init($url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
                    $html = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                }

                $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);

                $mpdf->useSubstitutions = true; // optional - just as an example
                $mpdf->SetHeader($url . "\n\n" . 'Page {PAGENO}');  // optional - just as an example
                $mpdf->CSSselectMedia='mdpf'; // assuming you used this in the document header
//                $mpdf->CSSselectMedia='global'; // assuming you used this in the document header
//                $mpdf->CSSselectMedia='style'; // assuming you used this in the document header
                $mpdf->setBasePath($url);
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                $mpdf->Output();


            }
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: You create an instance of mpdf before you start trying to retrieve a page then you create another instance when you are trying to create the output from the URL. What happens if you do NOT create the instance before retrieving the URL?

Comment: You are right is not doing anything more that instance, I removed it in the code.

now I manage to make a pdf  but the styling sheet is not taking into account despite  is being called by    $mpdf->CSSselectMedia='mdpf';